# Working as a self employed freelancer for an overseas company

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, self-employment, poland

I will soon be working on a self employed basis for a company based in Poland,but I'm still going to be based in the UK (working remotely/online as a consultant) and my question is do I need to pay taxes and national insurance in Poland as all my income will come from a Polish based company or in the UK as I will still be a UK resident? Is it at all possible?
Many thanks

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/412653/uk-poland-dtc.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you are *really* self employed, you will pay UK tax as a self employed person. This can be quite useful as there may well be some legitimate costs you can deduct.

If, however, you are in effect an employee, the tax situation will be different, and you will be taxed as an employee. If you continue to live in the UK, this will be subject to normal UK tax.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a UK resident, you'll pay UK tax and will need to do a tax return every year as a self-employed worker. It's really easy to file your taxes on the [HMRC website](https://www.gov.uk/topic/personal-tax/self-assessment) and you can also use an [online calculator](https://salarycalculatorpro.com) to work out how much money you need to save in tax and national insurance so you have it ready to pay.

If you want to pay to submit your self assessment, there is site called [SimpleTax](http://l.gosimpletax.com/zen/) which can do that and the main benefit is that it includes hints on what you can claim tax back on as a self-employed worker (although you can research that on the HMRC site and file your return for free).

Comment: Hi Ian. Is the calculator site yours? If you are affiliated with a site that you mention, your affiliation *must* be disclosed, per the [site's rules on self-promotion](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).